# How to map Dto objects to Entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have written a simple program that retrieves the exchange rate and some basic information about the currency using api(bank).

I would like to add a database to it so that the information is stored.

To do this, I have created a `Currency` entity that references a `DTO` and a `CurrencyRepository` that I have injected into a `CurrencyService`.

And at this point I am stuck, I don't really know how I can retrieve the values of `code`, `mid`, `effectiveDate` and save to the database.

Could someone please suggest what I should do to go further?

**DTO:CurrencyModelDto**

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.time.LocalDate;


@Getter
@Builder
public class CurrencyModelDto {
    private String code;
    private float mid;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate effectiveDate;
}
```

**Entity:Currency**

```
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Getter
public class Currency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private float mid;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate effectiveDate;
}
```

**Repository:CurrencyRepository**

```
import com.example.nbpmaster.repository.entity.Currency;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CurrencyRepository extends JpaRepository<Currency, Long> {
}
```

**Service:CurrencyService**

```
import com.example.nbpmaster.model.CurrencyModelDto;
import com.example.nbpmaster.repository.CurrencyRepository;
import com.example.nbpmaster.webclient.currency.CurrencyClient;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CurrencyService {

    private final CurrencyClient currencyClient;
    private final CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

    public CurrencyModelDto getCurrency() {
        return currencyClient.getCurrencyType("usd");

    }

}
```

**Client:CurrencyClient**

```
import com.example.nbpmaster.model.CurrencyModelDto;
import com.example.nbpmaster.webclient.dto.CurrencyDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class CurrencyClient {

    public static final String URL_API_NBP = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/";
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public CurrencyModelDto getCurrencyType(String value) {
        CurrencyDto currencyDto = callGetMethod("exchangerates/rates/a/{currency}/", CurrencyDto.class, value);
        return CurrencyModelDto.builder()
                .code(currencyDto.getCode())
                .mid(currencyDto.getRates().stream().findFirst().get().getMid())
                .effectiveDate(currencyDto.getRates().stream().findFirst().get().getEffectiveDate())
                .build();
    }

    private <T> T callGetMethod(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... objects) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(URL_API_NBP + url,
                responseType, objects);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink it - just do `new Currency()` and set all the fields (or better - pass them into the constructor) by taking values from `CurrencyModelDto`. And then save the Entity using the Repository.

And for god sake don't use additional libraries/frameworks to covert between Entity & DTO as others suggest. This is a very simple problem and it can be solved with very simple code - no need to introduce extra dependencies to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ModelMapper` class to convert `Dto to Model`  and vice versa. `ModelMapper` class has  `map()` which maps Model to Dto and vice versa.
Once you convert the Dto to Model you can call `currencyRepository.save()` to save the Model to the database.

You can refer [this link](https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to map Dto objects with Entities. Use [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) for the purpose. Next configure any Data base in your project and make connection to it. For ease it could be [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) data base. It's better to write set of CRUD REST controllers that will get all needed information from a site accordingly it's api specification and save it to DB. Then in main Spring Boot application class you code some logic applying to the REST controllers.